# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier Issue with Hibernate Dependent objects program

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I am working on a simple [hibernate dependent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch09.html#components-dependentobjects) program using `Oracle` as my database.

Here are my POJO classes:

**Person**

```
public class Person {
    private java.util.Date birthday;
    private Name name;
    private String key;
    ... getters & setters ...
}
```

**Name**

```
public class Name {
    char initial;
    String first;
    String last;
        ... getters & setters ...
}
```

Hibernate mapping file:

**person.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Person" table="person1">
        <id name="Key" column="pid" type="string">
            <generator class="uuid" />
        </id>
        <property name="birthday" type="date" />
        <component name="Name" class="Name"> <!-- class attribute optional -->
            <property name="initial" />
            <property name="first" />
            <property name="last" />
        </component>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have set the `hbm2ddl.auto` property as `update` in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file so tables are created when I execute my program.

Here is my simple program that tries to save an instance of Person object:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Name name = new Name();
        name.setFirst("First");
        name.setLast("First");
        name.setInitial('I');

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setBirthday(new Date());
        person.setName(name);

        session.save(person);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Now when I am executing this program, I am getting error while creation of table itself:

> 15:20:45,376 ERROR SchemaUpdate:235 - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: create
>   table person1 (pid varchar2(255) not null, birthday date, initial
>   char(1), first varchar2(255), last varchar2(255), primary key (pid))
>
> 15:20:45,376 ERROR SchemaUpdate:236 - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

I tried changing names of my properties in `Person` class as well as `Name` class but still I am facing this issue. Please let me know where I am doing mistake?

Comment: add type="character" for initial and give try

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan, I tried that now, but getting same error message.

Comment: thanks, M21B8, it's fix my problem too!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20969153/3270737

Comment: oracle reserved words :  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Invalid identifier doesn't mean your primary key is wrong, it means that one of the column identifiers is invalid. I believe your problem is the 'initial' column, which is a reserved word in Oracle.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, by giving a different column name it solved the issue.